# How do I check my NUC model from within Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, troubleshooting, intel-nuc

I'm trying to troubleshoot a video issue on an intel NUC, and need to get the model information. It's not convenient to get to the NUC itself, but I have a [relatively] healthy Windows 10 install what I have full admin rights on. How can I get the information from within the Windows operating system? (I'm not opposed to CLI operations.)

Comment: Look in Device Manager

Comment: Which sub-section?

Comment: Computer? .....

Comment: No help; just says `ACPI x64-based PC`; the details under `drivers` tab and `details` tab are also all generic...

Comment: does msinfo32.exe show you the name?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything under System Manufacturer. It shows the BaseBoard Manufacturer to be Intel Corp, but no Model or Name. Plenty of info about the OS, not about the hardware though...

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following command into a command prompt:

`wmic baseboard get manufacturer,product,serialnumber,version`

See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025060/mini-pcs.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you expand your answer a bit to better explain what to do with the information?  Thanks.

Comment: It's supposed to be entered in `command prompt`.